# Styling inner reCaptcha DIV?

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

I am trying to center the recaptcha div in my form. The outer reCaptcha DIV is acting weird and

```
margin: 0 auto;
float: none;
```

Has no effect. But the same code works on the inner div.

[image]

My question is, how can I customize the reCaptcha inner div, cause all I get is the following code from Google to integrate in my form (outer DIV)

```
<div id="c_rc" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-qLjkB6ixNKweR_2Kv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try targeting the inner div using the out div's class and querying down:

```
.g-recaptcha div div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, it's working flawlessly. Learned something new today.